# Proofs with binary trees

Tags: trees, proof-theory

Now I have a binary tree which is  How would I go about proving binary tree with $n$ leaves has exactly $2 n - 1$ nodes ?

Comment: Say you have $n$ leaves sitting around and you want to combine them into a single tree.  You need to use $n-1$ combining operations to make your tree, and each combining operation adds a node.  $n$ leaves + $n-1$ branch nodes = $2n-1$ total nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceed by induction. By finiteness we can always find a node which has two leaves. Cut them off then use induction hypothesis

Edit:

For example

```
          o
        /   \
       o     X  <---- Cut here
           /   \
          o     o
```

becomes

```
         o
      /     \
     o       o
```

also a binary tree, but with 1 fewer leaves and 2 fewer nodes.

Edit 2: So now we just say
$f(k) = f(k-1) +2$ which is $2(k-1) -1 + 2$ by induction giving us $2k-1$ as desired.

Comment: can you show me an example of this ?

Comment: if we can always find a node with 2 leaves, the first example I gave with the single node has no leaves ...so then wouldnt it mean its false

Comment: We need only find one node with two leaves. Unless you are dealing with the trivial tree we can always find such.

Comment: Oh! I think I just understood what you're saying. You're right to be worried about that, but the only time it happens is in the case of the tree with 3 nodes. Since that's the base case in your induction and you're checking it explicitly anyways you don't have to worry.